# Hidden friend to_json function unexpectedly resolves for shared_ptr

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup, nlohmann-json

The code below ([Goldbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nPveGzxjb)) compiles and runs (on both gcc and clang) and does what I would hope. But I'm surprised! I expected to have to use an adl_serializer specialisation (as opposed to the hidden friend here) for it to be able to find the `to_json`/`from_json` functions, as the `Example` class is hidden inside a `std::shared_ptr`.

So the question is, is this expected (and why?), or a bug in the compilers that might break my code when it gets fixed.

```
#include <memory>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

struct Example {
    int a;
    int b;

    Example(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b){};

    Example(Example&&) = delete;
    Example& operator=(Example&&) = delete;
    Example(Example&) = delete;
    Example& operator=(Example&) = delete;

    friend void to_json(nlohmann::json& j, const std::shared_ptr<Example>& p) {
        j = {{"a", p->a}, {"b", p->b}};
    }

    friend void from_json(const nlohmann::json& j,
                          std::shared_ptr<Example>& p) {
        p = std::make_shared<Example>(j.at("a").get<int>(),
                                       j.at("b").get<int>());
    }
};

int main() {
    auto j = R"({ "a" : 1, "b" : 2 })"_json;

    auto c = j.get<std::shared_ptr<Example>>();

    auto j2 = nlohmann::json(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend function definition not declared elsewhere is declared in the same namespace as the class it is defined in.

There are two reasons your `to_json` and `from_json` are found.

The first, and simplest reason is that `Example` is in the global namespace, so lookup will reach there if it doesn't find a match elsewhere.

The second reason is that adl looks at the namespace that `Example` is in.

> 3. For arguments whose type is a class template specialization, in addition to the class rules, the following types are examined and their associated classes and namespaces are added to the set
>
>    a. The types of all template arguments provided for type template parameters (skipping non-type template parameters and skipping template template parameters)

(from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl))

Comment: That second reason is what I was looking for, thanks! (The real-world example is not in global namespace). I can leave my code as-is happy that it's not about to break!

Comment: @tp288843 yeah, I suspected that you had `SomeNS::SomeClass` instead of `Example` :)